# How to explode a list of tuples consisting of a string and a list with n values?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples.

```
 l= [([a,b,c],'R1'),
     ([d],'R2'),
     ([e,f],'R3)]
```

Which I want to explode to

```
 l = [(a,'R1'),
      (b,'R1'),
      (c,'R1'),
      (d,'R2'),
      (e,'R3'),
      (f,'R3')]
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate over the tuples, and over the lists in the inner loop to obtain the corresponding tuples:

```
[(k,j) for i,j in l for k in i]
# [('a', 'R1'), ('b', 'R1'), ('c', 'R1'), ('d', 'R2'), ('e', 'R3'), ('f', 'R3')]
```